# Pandas dataframe replace method not working when using list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to transform this dataframe:

```
    col1    col2
0   [1, 0]  [0, 1]
1   [1, 1]  [1, 1]
2   [0, 1]  [1, 0]
3   [0, 1]  [1, 1]
4   [1, 1]  [0, 1]
5   [1, 0]  [1, 0]
```

Into this one:

```
    col1    col2
0   [1, 0]  [0, 1]
1        1       1
2   [0, 1]  [1, 0]
3   [0, 1]       1
4        1  [0, 1]
5   [1, 0]  [1, 0]
```

I tried to use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.replace([1,1], 1)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Maybe you could tell us how you wind up with a `df` of lists instead, and why you want to get columns with mixed types (list and ints) in the end?

Comment: Use tuples instead of lists. Dataframes with lists in behave in weird ways.

Answer (score 2):

Using `applymap`

```
df.applymap(lambda x :  1 if x==[1,1] else x )
Out[162]: 
     col1    col2
0  [1, 0]  [0, 1]
1       1       1
```